# socket.write() is causing my connection to terminate prematurely

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, logging, tcp

So i'm working on some code that connects to [a log server](http://logio.org/) and sends messages in a specific format. I create the socket, pass in the host and port number and then my client successfully connects. I know this because the connect event executes its callback. However when i try to write to the socket, the connection breaks. Any idea what could be causing this?

here is a snippet of what i'm doing.

```
function Harvester(options){
  const socket = new net.Socket();
  socket.connect({port:options.port, host:options.host}, ()=>{
    socket.write(`+node|${options.node}\r\n`);
  });
  socket.on('connect', (socket) => console.log('Connected to Log Harvester!'));
  socket.on('data', (data) => console.log('Message from Logio Server: ', data));
  socket.on('error', (error) => console.log('Error from Logio Server: ', error.message));
  socket.on('close', (error) => {
    console.log(!error ? 'Client connection closed' : 'Client connection closed with Error');
  });
  socket.on('end', () => console.log('Logio Connection Ended'));

  return {
    /**
     * Writes log to tcp socket
     * @param node
     * @param stream
     * @param level
     * @param message
     */
    log: (level, stream, message, done) => {
      socket.write(`+log|${stream}|${options.node}|${level}|${JSON.stringify(message)}\n`, function(err){
        if(err){ throw err }
        socket.end();
      });
      done(null, true);
    }
  }
}
```

is the server rejecting my connection? Do i need to somehow keep the connection Alive?

Comment: Whats the error you are seeing in the code on writing to the socket?

Comment: @Prabhu No errors. Just the client connection ended normally. Also `socket.on('close')` callback is also returning its `has_error` argument as falsew which means it is closing appropriately. I have seen some other examples online and it seems i have to implement some sort of reconnection logic for on the close event which feels very weird i must say.

Comment: can you check who is closing the socket? Get a tcpdump. That wil point you in right direction

Comment: Thanks @Prabhu Found the issue. i was closing the socket myself with socket.end in the socket.write callback which i shouldn't be doing.